# use CL var to perform hash lookup

Tags: ruby

Am trying to modify an exercise from a ruby lesson. Instead of hard coding a name in the script, I want to use it as a CL var and pass it to the script.

I start the script with an arg of "Mary" `ruby hashes.rb Mary`

Here is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# Script Name - hashes.rb
favorite_pizza = {
"John" => "Pepperoni",
"Tim" => "Mushroom",
"Mary" => "Cheese"
}
name=ARGV
puts favorite_pizza[name]`
```

I get blank output when I run the script. If I add the line `puts name` to the script, I see the output `Mary`, so I know the var is being set correctly. But now mater how I write `puts favorite_pizza[???]`, I never get expected `Cheese` output. In the brackets I have tried `[name]` and `[ARGV]` and `["#{name}"]` and `["#{ARGV}"]` and every other thing I can think of, google no help.

If I hard code it `puts favorite_pizza["Mary"]` I get expected output `Cheese`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `name = ARGV[0]` because `ARGV` is an `Array` http://jnoconor.github.io/blog/2013/10/13/a-short-explanation-of-argv/

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @engineersmnky has the right answer, it should be promoted to an answer, not just a comment. In my experience this is a small-seeming thing that trips up a lot of folks...

Comment: @TomHughes then please feel free to write it up.